# Android custom SeekBar with two values

Tags: android, user-interface, custom-component, seekbar

I need to create a custom SeekBar, which can show two different values. My idea is, that dragging the thumb will change background color of whole seek bar (first value) and there will also be a white horizontal line, which will show the second value.

[image: Custom Seekbar]

Can you help me achieve this?

One of my thoughts was to use

```
mySeekBar.setProgressDrawable(dynamicalyCreatedDrawable);
```

but I hope there should be a better solution. If there is not, can you at least point me, how to dynamicaly draw an image/drawable to use it like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
mySeekBar.setProgress(value1); // for the thumb
mySeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(value2); // for the white line
```

where `value1` and `value2` are between 0 and max.